# Conditional join in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join

So I'm having a little problem with linq. I want a join to be an OUTER JOIN or an INNER JOIN, depending on whether or not values are filtered on the table

OUTER JOIN:

```
var query = (from tblA in dc.tblA
             join tblB in GetMyTable() on tblA.Ref equals tblB.RefA into joinedTblB
             from tblB in joinedTblB.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select tblA);
```

INNER JOIN:

```
var query = (from tblA in dc.tblA
             join tblB in GetMyTable() on tblA.Ref equals tblB.RefA into joinedTblB
             from tblB in joinedTblB
             select tblA);
```

What I want is to combine this in the same query, and by checking some condition do either an OUTER JOIN or an INNER JOIN, something like this:

```
var query = (from tblA in dc.tblA
             join tblB in GetMyTable() on tblA.Ref equals tblB.RefA into joinedTblB
             from tblNEWB in ((checkCondition==false) ? joinedTblB.DefaultIfEmpty() : joinedTblB)
             select new {
                tblA.ValueA,
                tblNEWB.ValueB
             });
```

I was hoping this would work, but I get an error saying "InvalidOperationException: Member access 'System.String ValueB' of 'tblB' not legal on type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1 [tblB]"

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**:

What I want is an outer join, but linq did not produce the query I hoped for, when conditions are set on tlbB. Turning on SQL Profiler gives this query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblB ON tblA.Ref = tblB.REfA AND tlbB.Key = '100'
```

While the correct query should be:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblB ON tblA.Ref = tblB.RefA
WHERE tblB.Key = '100'
```

The reason for this is my GetMyTable-function that sets condition to the table in the join.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do exactly but know this: tblB goes out of scope after into statement. Then you are introducing another range variable for joinedTblB with the same name.

Comment: Why not do two separate queries and union them together?

Comment: Also it's not an inner join when you use into keyword. Explain what you wanna do clearly and we can help.

Comment: I'll try to explain. I want to do an INNER JOIN when a table has conditions, and I want to do an OUTER JOIN when the same table do not have conditions.Because of the complexity of the code and the conditions that can be set, I was hoping I could accomplish this in the JOIN-part of the query, and not in the WHERE-part.

Comment: Are you hundred per cent positive on what you name outer and inner joins? What you seem to want to achive looks like left join which takes all records from first set and join it with records from second set if those exist based on condition or null otherwise

Comment: here is an example on left join with LINQ http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/left-join-right-join-using-linq/

Comment: Maybe it will be better if you explain the problem without programming terms.

Comment: @vittore: U are correct - I do want an outer join. I'v updated the first post with an update

Comment: I believe that `LEFT OUTER JOIN tblB ON tblA.Ref = tblB.REfA AND tlbB.Key = '100'` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN tblB ON tblA.Ref = tblB.RefA
WHERE tblB.Key = '100'` are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to combine this in the same query, and by checking some condition do either an OUTER JOIN or an INNER JOIN

The first step to getting what you are asking for is to recognize that two distinct sql statements are required.  LinqToSql is not going to send your condition into the database so the database can figure out what kind of join should happen based on a value.

The second step, is to switch to the method syntax.  This syntax is more composable by conditions.

The third step, is to abandon anonymous types.  You have to do unpleasant things to declare the variables you need for query construction with those running around.  Just create a type with the properties you need and use that.

```
public class AandB
{
  public A TheA {get;set;}
  public B TheB {get;set;}
}

IQueryable<A> queryA =  dc.TblA.AsQueryable();

IQueryable<AandB> queryAandB = null;

if (checkCondition)
{
  //inner join
  queryAandB = queryA
    .Join(
      GetMyTable(),
      a => a.Ref, b => b.RefA,
      (a, b) => new AandB() {TheA = a, TheB = b}
    );
}
else
{
  // left join
  queryAandB = queryA
    .GroupJoin(
      GetMyTable(),
      a => a.Ref, b => b.RefA,
      (a, g) => new {a, g}
    )
    .SelectMany(
      x => x.g.DefaultIfEmpty(),
      (x, b) => new AandB(){TheA = x.a, TheB = b}
    );
}

List<AandB> results = queryAandB.ToList();
```

Comment: I was hoping Linq would "do the job" for me.
Thanks for the info, I probably go with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

if left join is what you need your first query should do the job

```
        (from tblA in dc.tblA
         join tblB in GetMyTable() on tblA.Ref equals tblB.RefA into joinedTblB
         from tblB in joinedTblB.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new {tblAField = tblA.F1 , tblBField = tblB == null ? null : tblB.F2);
```

inner join query would look like this

```
        (from tblA in dc.tblA
         join tblB in GetMyTable() on tblA.Ref equals tblB.RefA 
         select new { A = tblA, B = tblB } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this does exactly what you're looking for, but it should be close.

```
var query = from rowA in db.tblA
            join rowB in db.tblB on rowA.idB equals rowB.idB into b
            from item in b.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                rowA.ValueA,  
                rowB.ValueB
            };
```