# Change Join Type on a condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, ternary-operator

For example I have such a join :

```
from cust in customerList 
join prod in productList on cust.ProductId equals prod.Id
join veh in vehicleList on prod.VehicleId equals veh.Id into v
from veh in v.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {customerName = cust.Name, customerVehicle=veh.VehicleName}
```

As you can see there is a right join in the third and fourth lines. I want to make this join in a parametrized way.  I mean if I have a variable, I want to change the  join to this :

```
string x ="right";

if(x == right) //execute right join
{
    from cust in customerList 
    join prod in productList on cust.ProductId equals prod.Id
    join veh in vehicleList on prod.VehicleId equals veh.Id into v
    from veh in v.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {customerName = cust.Name, customerVehicle=veh.VehicleName}
}
else //execute inner join
{
    from cust in customerList 
    join prod in productList on cust.ProductId equals prod.Id
    join veh in vehicleList on prod.VehicleId equals veh.Id 
    select new {customerName = cust.Name, customerVehicle=veh.VehicleName}
}
```

I can do this with an `if` statement, but I think there is too much code and there is too much repetition. So can I apply this condition using ternary operator inside `join` line? Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

As I said I can do this with an if statement as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767847/conditional-join-in-linq). But my original code contains 13 nested joins. So writing ifs for every possibility would result a very ugly code. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional join in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767847/conditional-join-in-linq)

Comment: This really has been asked dozens of times before. Did you even google before posting the question?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes I have googled and I have seen that page before. But this doesn't answer my question. I really couldn't see answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have already mentioned the accepted answer in that question in my question. I'm looking for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try code

```
string x ="right";

var result= (from cust in customerList 
join prod in productList on cust.ProductId equals prod.Id
join veh in vehicleList on prod.VehicleId equals veh.Id into v
from veh in v.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {customerName = cust.Name,customerVehicle=veh.VehicleName}).ToList();

if(x=="right")
result=result.Where(c=>c.customerVehicle!=null).ToList();
```

X==right Then Null value Is Removed the result otherwise result default left join

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shouldn't I remove null values when X is left? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the test is backwards for your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is setup the common base part of the query in a variable then add on the rest of the query based on your condition.

```
string x ="right";
var qbase = from cust in customerList 
            join prod in productList on cust.ProductId equals prod.Id;

if(x == "right") { //execute right join
    qbase = from custprod in qbase
            join veh in vehicleList on prod.VehicleId equals veh.Id into v
            from veh in v.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {customerName = custprod.Name, customerVehicle=veh.VehicleName};
}
else { //execute inner join
    qbase = from custprod in qbase
            join veh in vehicleList on prod.VehicleId equals veh.Id 
            select new {customerName = custprod.Name, customerVehicle=veh.VehicleName};
}
```